# Is a security risk accesing HttpContext.Session with a static class attribute? ASP.NET Core razor mvc

Tags: c#, security, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an ASP.NET Core MVC Razor page in VS Code and using HttpContext.Session to pass data around. I want to use the session in a cshtml file but inflaters and other Microsoft stuff did not work for me. I came up with an idea to create a class `SessionHtml` with a static attribute of type `ISession` and assign it the `HttpContext.Session` when I first load it. Then, I can access it through the cshtml file:

```cs
Class SessionHtml
{
    static public ISession s;
}
```

My question is: Is this approach a security risk?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use static fields for session-specific data in ASP.NET. A static field can be accessed by any session, including sessions for other users.

If you need to access session variables through a static class, retrieve it at the point it is needed, e.g. by using an expression property

```
class SessionHtml
{
    static public ISession => HttpContext.Current.Session;
}
```

or a regular property

```
class SessionHtml
{
    static public ISession
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have acces to HttpContext.Current on the class, so that solution doesn't seems to work for me...